# Corona unit testing on linux

Tags: unit-testing, coronasdk

I want to create automatic unit tests for Corona on every push to a git repository. These unit tests should run on a Linux server. However, there is no Linux version of the Corona SDK. Is it possible to run unit tests for Corona on Linux? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona only runs on mobile devices or on its simulator (that only runs on Windows or Mac).

Even if you had enterprise version, it is still closed source, and the only thing the enterprise has more than the normal version is allow you to make a native program and link corona library with it yourself.

Thus, you can only unit test things you can run with the normal command line lua interpreter, anything that needs Corona stuff cannot be unit tested the way you want.